# ArrayList Manipulation?

Tags: c#, casting, arraylist

it is possible to store data in of two `arraylist` into `<list>`?

here's my code with two arrays that will merge:

```
ArrayList arrPrices = new ArrayList();
List<StockInfoPrice> lstStockInfoPrice = new List<StockInfoPrice>();
Util oUtils = new Util(); 
arrPrices = oUtils.GetPrices(SymbolIndex);

ArrayList arrDetails = new ArrayList();
List<StockInfoDetails> lstStockInfoDetails = new List<StockInfoDetails>();
Util oUtils = new Util(); 
arrPrices = oUtils.GetDetails(SymbolIndex);
```

Comment: I think with the third `arrPrices` you meant `arrDetails`, huh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with linq simply:

```
lstStockInfoPrice.AddRange(arr1.Cast<StockInfoPrice>());
lstStockInfoPrice.AddRange(arr2.Cast<StockInfoPrice>());
```

See [**`Cast`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) in `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move the value from `arrPrices` to `lstStockInfoPrice` and `lstStockInfoDetails`, you could iterate over the array list and put the elements in the list. Something like this:

```
foreach(var o in arrPrices)
{
  lstStockInfoPrice.Add(o); // or Add((StockInfoPrice)o)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

You could try the following if oUtils.GetPrices(SymbolIndex) returns StockInfoPrice;

```
lstStockInfoPrice.AddRange(oUtils.GetPrices(SymbolIndex));
```

Answer (score 1):

I this Util class isn't your own, then you're stuck with Marius' answer. However, if you control that Util class then you could make the GetPrices and GetDetails methods return someting with type IEnumerable and IEnumerable respectively.

Then, you can add the whole lot to another list with List.AddRange() method.

As an aside, your allocation in the declaration of arrPrices is a waste of time - the allocated object is never used and will then be subject to garbage collection.

Your GetPrices() method returns an ArrayList  - ie, a *new* arrayList, and

```
arrPrices = oUtils.GetPrices(SymbolIndex);
```

simply makes arrPrices refer to the new list. There are then no references to the one you allocated when you declared arrPrices, so it's thrown away.

Do it like this:-

```
ArrayList arrPrices;
List<StockInfoPrice> lstStockInfoPrice = new List<StockInfoPrice>();
Util oUtils = new Util(); 
arrPrices = oUtils.GetPrices(SymbolIndex);
```